# Can't find vcard attachment with the mail

Tags: iphone, ios, vcf-vcard, email-attachments, mfmailcomposer

I am trying to send an email from my iphone, with a vcard as attachment. When I am sending the mail, the vcard is being attached with the mail. But the receiver of the mail can't find the vcard  attachment. Help needed.
This is the code  I have used

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Vcard" ofType:@"vcf"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"text/x-vcard" fileName:@"Vcard.vcf"];
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution... Isubmitted a bug on Apple radar about it. MFMailcomposer has a bug in which you have to send an image along with your extra attachments in order to get the weird items like a pdf to work...  try this and replace the pdf with your card:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
NSString *emailSubject = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"MedicalProfile"];
[controller setSubject:emailSubject];


NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", profileName];
NSString *saveDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSString *saveFileName = fileName;
NSString *documentPath = [saveDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:saveFileName];  

*** YOU MUST INCLUDE AN IMAGE OR THE PDF ATTATCHMENT WILL FAIL!!!***
// Attach a PDF file to the email 
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:documentPath];    
[controller addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:fileName];


// Attach an image to the email
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"miniDoc" ofType:@"png"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
[controller addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"doctor"];


[controller setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s Medical Profile attatched!", profileName] isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller release];
```